# Are these 2 complex manifolds homeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

This is an example give in Kodaira's Complex Manifolds and Deformation of Complex Structures, Chpt 2, Sec 2, Example 2.10

Consider $M=\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$ with $S=0\times\mathbb P^1$ where $0$ is identified as $0\in\mathbb C\subset\mathbb P^1$ and $\mathbb C$ is complex plane. Denote $W'(\epsilon)=W(\epsilon)=U_{\epsilon}\times \mathbb P^1$ with $U_{\epsilon}=\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<\epsilon\}$. Consider the following gluing map to obtain $M_n=M-W(\epsilon)\cup W(\epsilon)$ via the following identification map. 
$(W(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)-S)\to (W'(\frac{1}{2}\epsilon)-S)$ is defined by $(z,t)\to (z,t/z^n)$. (This is essentially replace $S$ by some twisted $S$.)

The book has shown $M$ not homeomorphic to $M_1$ via computing intersection number on the 2nd homology. The result is obviously extendable to $M$ not homeomorphic to $M_n$.

The book only mentions that for $n\neq m$ $M_n$'s complex structure is different from $M_m$'s complex structure.

Update: I have found in a [link](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hirzebruch_surfaces) that intersection form $H_2(M_n)$ has some basis element with self intersection $n$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Even from that intersection form, I cannot conclude whether $M_n$ not homeomorphic to $M_m$ for $m\neq n$. Furthermore, what is the 2 cycle that gives self intersection $n$ for $M_n$? How do I tell whether $M_n$ not homeo to $M_m$ for $m\neq n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude it because the intersection form is a topological invariant. By the way the self-intersection is $-n$ I believe (unless you took $n$ negative in your question, but it's important that the self-intersection is negative).

To explicitly identify the cycle : here is a really beautiful construction of Hirzebruch surfaces which also answer your question. It's easy to see that $M_1$ is the blow-up of $\Bbb P^1$ at a point, so a $\Bbb P^1$-bundle over $\Bbb P^1$, say with projection $\pi : X \to \Bbb P^1$. The exceptional divisor $E$ is such that $\pi_{|E} : E \to \Bbb P^1$ is an isomorphism, hence we can think of $E$ as a section (indeed it's often called the exceptional section). There is a procedure which allows you to construct $M_n$ from $M_{n+1}$ : pick a point on $p \in E$ (the exceptional divisor), blow-up at this point and contract the fiber $\pi^{-1}(\pi(p))$. Such a transformation is called a Nagata transform. This gives you explicitly the exceptional cycle (the image of $E$ by these transformation). The same construction can be reversed by first blowing-up a point outside $E$ and contracting the corresponding fiber.

Comment: It's also worth saying that if one take as definition $M_n = \Bbb P(\mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O(n))$ then there is a canonical isomorphism $M_n  \cong M_{-n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Recall the cohomology ring is homotopy invariant, so in particular, the intersection form, up to change of basis, is homeomorphism invariant.

We have the possible self-intsersection of a 2-cycle:
$$(a\cdot[\text{fibre}]+b\cdot[\text{base}])^2=-nb^2+2ab$$
where "base" is represented by the copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is the point $0\in\mathbb{P}^1$ on every fibre.
If $n\equiv0\pmod2$ then all self-intersection numbers are even.  If $n\equiv1\pmod2$ then we get some odd numbers.  So $M_n$ and $M_m$ homeomorphic $\Rightarrow m\equiv n\pmod2$.

Conversely, note that $M_n$ are $S^2$-bundles over $S^2$, and these are classified by the gluing map along an equatorial $S^1$ of $S^2=D^2\cup_{S^1}D^2$.  Since $\operatorname{Aut}S^2=SO(3)$ (you could use $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ if you want, the calculation is the same), we have $$[\text{equatorial }S^1, SO(3)]=\pi_1(SO(3))=C_2.$$
So $m\equiv n\pmod{2}$ implies $M_n$ and $M_m$ are homeomorphic.

For complex structures, see Nicolas's answer.

Comment: Really nice answer ! It's also nice to look at the real case (i.e when we take real points), then we get torus or Klein bottle according to the parity, so it matches with your answer.